# Read grb2 files is very slow

Tags: python, grib, pygrib, cfgrib

Reading a grb2 file of about 100 megabytes takes me 5 minutes with the following code:

```
import cfgrib
datasets = cfgrib.open_datasets(grib_path, backend_kwargs={'indexpath': ''})
```

Is there any way or library with which I can read these files more quickly?

Comment: Try to use; `xarray.open_dataset(grib_path, engine='cfgrib')` And share your file that we can reproduce your issue. And open_datasets returns a List of all subsets you do not need to pass `backend_kwargs={'indexpath': ''}`.

Comment: the problem is that grib2 files are very compressed and difficult to read

Comment: The speed is the same with the function you told me

Comment: Do you have the right grib tables available for eccodes? And please upload the file to a cloud storage and share a link. Then i will check whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

it's actually an annoying issue that's being raised here. With a 12Mb Grib file, to read a single field, cfgrib takes 19 seconds compared to 0.02 seconds with pynio! more than 900 times more!

ps : parallel = True gives as result : open_dataset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parallel'

Code with pynio :

```
    import time
    import Nio
    import xarray as xr
    start = time.time()

    filename  = "full_path_to_the_grb2_file"
    parameter = "parameter_name"
    ds  = xr.open_dataset(filename, engine="pynio")
    var = ds.get(parameter)
    end = time.time()
    print("Elapsed time = ", round(end-start,5))
```

Code with cfgrib :

```
    import time
    import cfgrib
    import xarray as xr
    start = time.time()

    filename  = "full_path_to_the_grb2_file"
    parameter = "parameter_name"
    start = time.time()
    ds = xr.open_dataset(filename, engine="cfgrib", backend_kwargs={"indexpath":""}) 
    var = ds.get(parameter)
    end = time.time()
    print("Elapsed time = ", round(end-start,5))
```

For example if you try with a grib2 file from GFS-wave (NOMADS) :

```
    filename = "gfswave.txxz.global.0p25.f000.grib2"
```

for the parameter : Significant height of combined wind waves and swell

```
    parameter = "HTSGW_P0_L1_GLL0"  # with pynio"
    parameter = "swh"               # corresponding parameter with cfgrib
```

Comment: Thats amazing!! Can you show a example of Code with pynio?

Comment: @jay : I have added examples of both pynio and cfgrib code.

Comment: The `parallel` parameter works with `open_mfdataset`, though I did not have any speed up from it - 2MB grib file takes full 8 seconds to open. pynio is a Conda package - is there a Conda-independent alternative?

Answer (score -1):

You can activate parallel read to enhance the reading speed:

```
import xarray
data = xarray.open_mfdataset(grib_path, engine='cfgrib', parallel=True)
```

Comment: open_dataset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parallel'

Comment: The function call should be `xarray.open_mfdataset(..., parallel=True)`. Then the argument is accepted though it did not speed up reading the data for me.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. You are free to edit answers. ;)